# SQL Contains Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

Can someone explain this to me? I have two queries below with their results.

---

**query**:

```
select * from tbl where contains([name], '"*he*" AND "*ca*"')
```

**result-set**:

> Hertz Car Rental
>
> Hemingyway's Cantina

---

**query**:

```
select * from tbl where contains([name], '"*he*" AND "*ar*"')
```

**result-set**:

> nothing

---

The first query is what I would expect, however I would expect the second query to return "Hertz Car Rental". Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how '*' works in full-text searching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think SQL Server is interpreting your strings as prefix_terms. The asterisk is not a plain old wildcard specifier. Fulltext and Contains are word oriented. For what you are trying to do, you would be better off using plain old LIKE instead of CONTAINS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: +1 the '*' wildcard can only be used for prefix matching, the first one in the pattern string must be ignored in the first example.  @hatchet is right on recommending LIKE instead for this usage (or just drop the wildcards all together if you want really "fuzzy" matching?)

Comment: I guess I was fundamentally misunderstanding everything, wasn't I. Thanks to all of you for the clarification. I think we'll just go to prefix searching as we've already determined that LIKE isn't performant enough.

Answer (score 4):

"*" only works as a suffix. If you use it as a prefix, the table needs to be scanned no matter what and the index is useless. At that point, you might as well do

```
  Select * From Table Where (Name Like '%he%') And (Name Like '%ar%')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try replacing * with % to see how it goes.

```
select * from tbl where contains([name], '"%he%" AND "%ar%"')
```

Comment: That does not do anything. CONTAINS is not LIKE.

Comment: `%` vs `*` doesn't seem to break the first query; why would it mess up the second?