# SQL Server Full-Text search fails when searching more than one word

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, nopcommerce

**Symptoms:**

Searching for a single word (i.e. "Snap") works

Searching for another word contained in the same field (i.e. "On") also works

Searching for "Snap On" at the same time returns 0 results, even though it shouldn't.

**The setup:**

SQL Server 2008 R2 with Advanced Features

nopCommerce 3.0

**Things I have done:**
I added the Product.MetaKeywords column to the full text search catalog

I added a bit into the Stored Procedure that performs the search to search through the MetaKeywords

Now the nopCommerce boards are fairly slow, but I'm positive the problem is within the SQL Stored Procedure anyway, so I figured I would ask for some SQL Server help here, even if you aren't familiar with the nopCommerce web app, you may have some information you can help me with.

The stored procedure in question is too large to post entirely here, but basically it dynamically adds "OR" or "AND" in between the keyword searches to generate the phrase used in a Contains clause.  It selects through several unions various searchable fields by using Contains.

Here is the bit I added into the stored procedure

```
SET @sql = @sql + '
UNION
SELECT p.Id
FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
WHERE '
IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
    SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[MetaKeywords], @Keywords) '
ELSE
    SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[MetaKeywords]) > 0 '
```

@Keywords, at this point, if I am reading the procedure correctly, has a value of: `"Snap* AND On*"`

I don't understand why my query of "Snap On" returns 0 results, but "Snap" and "On" individually work fine.

The minimum search length is set to 1, so it's not that.

I should add that searching for `"Snap* OR On*"` works, but I cannot use OR because then searching for "Snap On" will also return "Snap Dragon" and other unrelated things.

**--EDIT--**

The problem wasn't any of that. I got some advice elsewhere and the problem was actually the stoplist. I managed to fix my issue simply by changing the stoplist on the product table from `<system>` to `<off>`.

To do this, follow these steps.

- browse to your table in SQL Server management studio
- Right click on the table and select "Full-Text Index"
- Select "Properties" under "Full-Text Index"
- In the "General" Tab, change "Full-Text Index Stoplist" to `<off>`

I had to do it this way because I was unable to get the transact SQL to work. It kept telling me there was no such object as the table I was attempting to modify. If anyone can provide any insight on how the `Alter fulltext index` statement works, I'm interested, because I was following the example on the MSDN page to the T and it just kept telling me there was no such object named Product.

Comment: Can you try '"Snap*" OR "On*"'  (quote each term, so OR is not considered par of your search term)

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk is not a plain old wildcard. If you are using it anywhere other than at the end of a search term, you're probably not using it correctly. See answers to a similar question

[SQL Contains Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962270/sql-contains-question/6962396#6962396)

In your case, each search term must be quoted separately. See this example from the docs http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.90).aspx

```
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*" OR "full*"');
```