# SQL Server 2012 Full text indexing less than 3 char words not indexed properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing

I have table with a `nvarchar(100)` column which has data like

```
abc/k/p/0001
def/p/i/0002
abcdef2312
```

Code:

```
Declare @searchtext nvarchar(100)
Declare @searchtext2 nvarchar(100)

set @searchtext2 = 'abc/k/p/0001'
set @searchtext = '"*'+@searchtext2+'*"'
```

Query 1:

```
Select * from table1 where Contains(column1, @searchtext)
```

Query 2:

```
Select * from table1 where column1 like '%' + @searchtext2 + '%'
```

Query 1 fails to return records but query 2 returns records

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962270/sql-contains-question